# Fetch coredate record where boolean column value is NO or nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I want to fetch data from my entity where the value of specific column(isDelete) is `nil or` `NO` . I use below code:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [LIUtility sharedUtility].managedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NumberStorage" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetch setEntity:entity];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(type = %d) and isDelete != YES",type];
        [fetch setPredicate:predicate];

 allCardNumber = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
```

but it is not working.

How should I query this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW1), you must explicitly test for nil:

> **Testing for Null**
>   If you want to match null values, you must include a specific test in addition to other comparisons

So, amend your predicate to:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(type = %d) AND (isDelete == NO OR isDelete == nil)",type];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [LIUtility sharedUtility].managedObjectContext;
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NumberStorage" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetch setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(type = %d) and isDelete != %@",type, @YES];
[fetch setPredicate:predicate];

allCardNumber = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
```

It is nice if you set default value for the boolean properties in model editor instead of having it as a nil.

Comment: Let me describe more, in my previous version , I had a entity that has not the column "isDelete" . In the new version I create this column and set the default value to NO. I alos do the lightweight migration. Now I install the new version. I expect that when I query with "isDelete=No" then my records from previous version fetch too. But they do not fetch. They will fetch only if I do not query on isDelete column. Right now I try your code too but it is not working too :(